# 404 when trying to access controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.1

In a clear and working web-app template I'm adding a new controller, but then I cannot access it through browser - 404 on any action.

For example, when I add a new empty one with action index() (no params), and then create an empty view for it - 404. And for complex controller created with scaffolding as well. But it still working fine for those default Home and Account controllers.

How to find what and when goes wrong?

UPD controller and routes code, nothing too custom:

```
namespace yaapelsinko.UI.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Test
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}

namespace yaapelsinko.UI
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some controller code, post the contents of your route config file

Comment: done, but nothing interesting there - just clean templates VS gives you.

Comment: Have you tried debugging by putting a breakpoint at the beginning of that controller to see i

Comment: I've tried to put NotSupportedException into action. It never called. I assume if I get 404 on a controller, application just never instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller class should inherit from apiController, not controller.  I believe that should fix it.  If not, can you post your url (without the domain stuff)?

Comment: Why api? It was just another MVC-controller, and, again, it was created by add/controller command, so it definitely follows the template. Urls were /Test/Index, /Test, just as usual. Anyway, I've "solved" that problem by deleting entire UI project (it was almost empty anyway) and recreating it. Now it is just an academic interest "what was that"...